# Node JS socket.on() client side glitch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am learning Node JS and have come across some strange behavior which perhaps someone knows the answer to.  A lot of tutorials posts I have come across are saying to use "socket.on('connect', function(){ blah blah }); on the client side to send a request to the server. Esentially this is supposed to stop a call from being sent to the server until the server has established a connection with the client.  However when I test the code, it works as long as the client html is run first, and then node js is launched afterwards.  If node js is running the server code first, and then the client side html is launched, the emit function doesn't call out to the server for some reason.  If I omit the socket.on function and go straight to my socket.emit function, the server receives the emit function from the client. If node js is not running first, the client side html continues to run until node js launches the server script, at which point the client connects, and emits the request automatically. Does anyone know why this is happening? As I said, I am still learning Sockets and Node JS, so I would rather understand the behavior instead of just continuing on with my coding, even though I got it to work. Any information you provide would be extremely valuable. Thanks.:)

```js
// Server side

var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(1111, function(){ console.log("Server Listening"); });
var io = socket(server);

io.on('connect', function(socket) {

 socket.on('Contact', function(data) {

  socket.join(data);
  console.log(data); // just to test if data is sent
  
 });

});
```

```html
// Client in head section

<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:1111");

function Setup() { // called when page has loaded

  //blah blah blah lots and lots of code
  
  var data = "blahblah"; // room to join
  
  socket.on('connect', function(){
  
    socket.emit('Contact', data);
   });
}
   
 // If I remove the socket.on function it works flawlessly everytime.  Left in, it will only fire if the
 // node js server file is launched after the client launches
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're calling the `Setup()` function manually some time later (in the page load event perhaps, based on the comment). This means you're creating a race condition: If the server connects before the page load event, the connect event happens too fast and you attach your listener only after it happens.

So essentially what's happening is this:

First Case (server starts after client)

- Client HTML loads, script executes
- Client starts attempting connection to server
- Client assets finish loading, `Setup()` is called
- Client `connect` listener attached to socket
- Server starts up, starts accepting connections
- Server accepts client connection
- Client `connect` listener fires, emits Contact event

Second Case (client starts after server)

- Server starts up, starts accepting connections
- Client HTML loads, script executes
- Server accepts client connection
- There is currently no `connect` listener, so nothing happens
- Client assets finish loading, `Setup()` is called
- Client `connect` listener attached to socket
- Silence...

To fix, you should only call `io.connect(...)` in the same scope that you add listeners to it. This means either moving the `socket.on('connect', ...)` outside of Setup() or moving the `io.connect()` inside Setup() (probably better).

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the explaination. I'll give it a try.